# Create file for secret in pre-install hook

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart and I need to create a file before installing all my resources to be able to store it in a secret. I have been reading about Helm Hooks and I think I can create a hook, insert my script files, run my script and generate the file I need, where I'm lost is on how can I get my file out of the pod and insert it as a secret.

These are my hooks:

Secret hook for the scripts:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hlf-genesis-block
  namespace: hlf
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
type: Opaque
data:
  createfile.sh: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "scripts/createfile.sh" | b64enc }}
```

Job Hook:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "post-install-hook"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: scripts
        secret:
          secretName: scripts
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: channel-config
        image: "ubuntu:20.04"
        command: ["bash", "-c", "
                domainname=\"{{ .Values.domainName }}\"
                ./createfile.sh \"$domainname\"
              "]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/
          name: scripts
          readOnly: true
```

Final secret file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hlf-genesis-block
  namespace: hlf
type: Opaque
data:
  secret.txt: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "generatedfile.txt" | b64enc }}
```

I was thinking maybe like assigning a variable using something like this inside the job:

```
{{ $secret := echo generatedfile.txt }}
```

But I haven't found a function for it, or mapping a volume temporarily, but even that way I haven't been able to figure out how to take out the  secret from my job or the temporal storage, as the .Files.Get works from where the kubectl is running...

Or maybe running kubectl from inside the job to create the secret? although then I wont be able to delete the secret on uninstall.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

EDIT:

Is it possible to modify the secret value by modifiing the mapped secret volume? I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going over https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable and https://github.com/bitnami/charts to reuse existing solution

Helm Template https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/rabbitmq/templates/secrets.yaml uses randAlphaNum template function https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#randalphanum-randalpha-randnumeric-and-randascii to generate the secret.

The problem with randAlphaNum generating new secret every time helm install/upgrade command is run is solved by https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3053#issuecomment-782837107 using lookup template function https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function. Below code is copied from https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3053#issuecomment-782837107

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: foobar-secret
type: Opaque
{{- $previous := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "foobar-secret" }}
data:
  {{- if $previous }}
  foobarPassword: {{ $previous.data.foobarPassword }}
  {{- else if .Values.foobarPassword }}
  foobarPassword: {{ .Values.foobarPassword | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- else }}
  foobarPassword: {{ randAlphaNum 40 | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

EDIT :

Init Demo Pod Definiton : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: init-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: channel-config
      mountPath: /run/channel-config
  # These containers are run during pod initialization
  initContainers:
  - name: channel-config
    image: "ubuntu:20.04"
    command: ["bash", "-c", "cd /run/channel-config && ./createfile.sh \"{{ .Values.domainName }}\""]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: channel-config
      mountPath: "/run/channel-config"
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: channel-config
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Hi @sagar-velankar thank you for your answer but my problem is that I need to run a script to generate the secret, and I don't know how to take the secret out of the pod into the secret after creating it, I'm thinking of using kubectl patch secret from the pod but I was hopping to find a more "helm style way" to generate it. I'm going to check the charts though thanks

Comment: ok. Sorry I did not understand your question. Can you use initContainer to run the script createfile.sh to generate the password in emptyDir Volume which is also mounted by the main container ? Example is https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/ . I will edit the answer with the init Demo Pod Definition. Init Containers need to complete before the main containers are started.

Comment: hmmm this could work, but I actually need it to update 2 deployments, and I don't think the file would end up being the same for both, I think it has some time marks in it. The case is for a hyperledger fabric blockchain, the file I'm creating its the genesis block and after creating it, 2 different deployments for orderer1 and orderer2 use it. I can create it with the job and share a storage between them all but I would prefer a secret to the storage though.

Comment: you know I didn't knew initContainers option its really cool thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using storages its a good solution, but for the sake of completion this is the way I did it using secrets:

I created the final secret with a phony value

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hlf-genesis-block
  namespace: hlf
type: Opaque
data:
  secret.txt: {{ "empty" | b64enc }}
```

Then I created a role and a rolebinging to be able to modify the secret from the job

Role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: update-secrets
  namespace: hlf
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - patch
```

RoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: update-secrets
  namespace: hlf
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: update-secrets
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: hlf
```

Finally I didn't use a hook as the job runs much faster than my deployments that need to map some persistent volumes and changed the command like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "genesis-job"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: scripts
        secret:
          secretName: scripts
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: channel-config
        image: "myrepo/fabric-tools-with-k8s"
        command: ["bash", "-c", "./createfile.sh \"{{ .Values.domainName }}\" && cat genesis.block | base64 > encoded.block  && genesis=$(cat encoded.block | tr -d '\n') && patch="[{\"op\":\"replace\",\"path\":\"/data/genesis.block\",\"value\":\"$genesis\"}]" && kubectl patch secret hlf-genesis-block --type=json -p="$patch""]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/
          name: scripts
          readOnly: true
```

Comment: You could use pre-install hook job called init to create the secret and another post-delete hook job called cleanup to delete the secret. Then you dont have to worry about Deployment being created before secret is created. Also I recommend to add resourceName = secretname to ClusterRole for better security https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources and also use a new serviceaccount for the jobs to avoid giving privileges to default serviceaccount

Comment: good advice I will change it that way, thank you